# How to use transactions in the async csharp-SQLite wrapper?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using the  csharp-SQLite wrapper in my C# project.

Before, I used the same library but the syncro functions instead of the async.

I could use BeginTransaction. This function does not exist in the async calls.

How can I start and commit a transaction using async calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found it in Stackoverflow. The function is RunInTransactionAsync:

```
await MyDatabaseManager.Connection.RunInTransactionAsync((SQLiteConnection connection) =>
{
  foreach (Hotel _hotel in listUpdates)
  {
    result = connection.Update(_hotel);

    if (result == 0)
    {
      connection.Insert(_hotel);
    }
  }
});
```